# "Seems like an overkill" vs. "seems like overkill"

Tags: grammaticality, articles, indefinite-articles, uncountable-nouns

I’m wondering if an article is used with the word *overkill*:

- Something seems like an overkill (to me).
- Something seems like overkill (to me).

Which is grammatical?

Comment: You say "seems like overkill", not "seems like an overkill". [Have a look](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seems+like+overkill%2Cseems+like+an+overkill&year_start=1965&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). VTCAGR.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this website. I'll use it more often.

Comment: It doesn't tell the whole story all the time (it gets its data from books and magazines, not conversations). But it's a great  reference tool for questions like the one you asked here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what is meant by *overkill*.

[ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/overkill) has *overkill* as a mass (uncountable) noun:

> noun [mass noun]
>   **1** excessive use, treatment, or action
>   **2** the amount by which destruction or the capacity for destruction exceeds what is necessary

[Interestingly, OED indicates sense 2 came first, and the word has been applied more generally so that sense 1 is now what *overkill* usually means.]

Because it's a mass noun, *overkill* will not usually take the indefinite article.

Mass nouns **can** take the indefinite article when you are talking about a **type** of the thing: "Foccaccia is a bread". However it's difficult to conceive a sentence where *overkill* would fit like that.

Comment: Sense 2 did indeed come first. It came from military analyses of the nuclear arsenals of the Cold War powers. It was also called "pounding the rubble" from which came the joke that the effect of the arms race on the USSR's economy was "pounding the ruble".